# What is shallow resource controller

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, laravel-8

In my laravel project I want to make a **controller** for a modell. I don't need views, only these operations: **store, destroy, update**. I heard something about shallow resource contoller but I didn't find anything about it.

Is there any **flag** or something to generate controller only with these operations?
I know I could do it with resource controller but Is there such a thing as **shallow resource controller**?

Comment: There are [partial resource routes](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/controllers#restful-partial-resource-routes) if that helps

Comment: Looks good at first glance.

Comment: As @apokryfos mentioned, you want an [API Resource controller](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/controllers#api-resource-routes), you don't want the view, just the logic

Answer (score 1):

yes there is such a flag.

```
php artisan make:controller SomeController --api
```

If that is not what you want, you could also just create the full controller through:

```
php artisan make:controller SomeController --resource
```

and then remove the ones you don't need.